# How to draw the pushpin issue inside the ios app?

Tags: ios, angular, autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

I am using the "Autodesk.BIM360.Extension.PushPin" extension inside the forge viewer to enable push pins.

Pushpins could create and restore all good in the web viewer, but when I run the app on ios, the pushpin extension cannot be loaded and there is no error message reported in the console. However, android works well.

[image]

I am using the angular and ionic to build my app on different platforms.  the tutorial available [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/pushpins/create-pushpin/)

```
this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.BIM360.Extension.PushPin')
   .then(function (extension) {
              issueExt = extension;
              if (issueExt.pushPinManager) {
                issueExt.removeAllItems();
              }
              issueExt = extension;
              issueExt.startCreateItem({label: 'New', status: 'open', type: 'issues'});
            });       
}
```

I checked some documents about create the pushpin issue by SVG, markup works good but since I use the pushpin extension on the website also, I want use the same way to restore and create the pushpin issue. Could I build the pushpin data such as pinViewerState, pinPosition, pinStatus by myself? or If some one has experience building the pushpin with ios app? Any help would be appreciated.

I check the loaded extension in the console log. It seems that pushpin extension is not loaded when deploying in the ios app.

mobile log:
[image]

web log:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were trying to load the Viewer library from a local source rather than our CDN? That won't work as the library does not support relative reference.

Just tested the extension on iOS 13 and it worked fine:
[image]